# Android unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface on GooglePlaystore

Tags: java, android, google-play

I was trying to submit an update of my app to Google play. Now the problem is that they sent me an email saying that

> Your app(s) has unsafe implementation of the Hostnameverifier.

I tried searching for the solutions but no luck.
Here is my APIClient.java which handles the connections:

```
package com.sixix.user.data.network;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sixix.user.BuildConfig;
import com.sixix.user.MvpApplication;
import com.sixix.user.R;
import com.sixix.user.data.SharedHelper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

//import com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor;

public class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
//    private static X509TrustManager x509TrustManager;

    public static ApiInterface getAPIClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            try {
                retrofit = new Retrofit
                        .Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                        .client(getHttpClient(MvpApplication.getInstance().context))

                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
//    private static SSLContext getSSLConfig(Context context) throws CertificateException, IOException,
//            KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
//
//        // Loading CAs from an InputStream
//        CertificateFactory cf = null;
//        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
//
//        Certificate ca;
//        // I'm using Java7. If you used Java6 close it manually with finally.
//        try (InputStream cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.__6ixtaxi_com)) {
//            ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
//        }
//
//        // Creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
//        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
//        KeyStore keyStore   = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
//        keyStore.load(null, null);
//        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
//
//        // Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore.
//        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
//        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
//        tmf.init(keyStore);
//        // Creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
//        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
//        x509TrustManager= (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
//        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
//
//        return sslContext;
//    }

    private static OkHttpClient getHttpClient(Context context) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.__6ixtaxi_com); //(.crt)
        Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore.
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,x509TrustManager )
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new AddHeaderInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(new DecryptedPayloadInterceptor(new DecryptedPayloadInterceptor.DecryptionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public String decrypt(String stream) throws Exception {
                        if (!SharedHelper.apiState.equals("")) {
                            SharedHelper.apiState="";

                            return new String(Base64.decode(stream , Base64.DEFAULT), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        }else {
                            return stream;
                        }
                    }


                }))
                //.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
                .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
    }

    private static class AddHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            builder.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            builder.addHeader(
                    "Authorization",
                    SharedHelper.getKey(MvpApplication.getInstance(), "access_token", ""));
            Log.d("RRR TOKEN", SharedHelper.getKey(MvpApplication.getInstance(), "access_token", ""));
            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        }
    }
}
class DecryptedPayloadInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final DecryptionStrategy mDecryptionStrategy;

    public interface DecryptionStrategy {
        String decrypt(String stream) throws Exception;
    }

    public DecryptedPayloadInterceptor(DecryptionStrategy mDecryptionStrategy) {
        this.mDecryptionStrategy = mDecryptionStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            Response.Builder newResponse = response.newBuilder();
            String contentType = response.header("Content-Type");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contentType)) contentType = "application/json";
            String decrypted = null;
            if (mDecryptionStrategy != null) {
                try {
                    decrypted = mDecryptionStrategy.decrypt(response.body().string());
                    Log.e("sdsd",decrypted);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("sdsd",e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No decryption strategy!");
            }
            newResponse.body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), decrypted));
            return newResponse.build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this support article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426) help?

Comment: Not at all but i though it would but all in vain

Comment: There's no HostnameVerifier in the code snippets you posted (other than in the imports section). Also note that the problem can also come from a library you're using.

Comment: Yes but can you help me to fix it in the answers section with my code edited?